# Defining a dummy Objective in Pyomo

Tags: python, pyomo

So I'm trying to structure an MCP for Pyomo (with Python 3) where there's only one solution which fits all the complementary conditions, making the objective function redundant. Do I need to define an objective at all, or is there any way to define a dummy objective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the solver that you are using. Some solvers will complain without the presence of an objective. My favorite ways to add a dummy include:

- `model.dummy = Objective(expr=1)`
- `model.dummy_var = Var(bounds=(0, 1))` with `model.dummy = Objective(expr=model.dummy_var)`